# First Procedure: Is my theory correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first procedure. I am trying to set it up so it will calculate these 3 values each day when the data is updated in the database itself. It will be set to run right after the database is updated each night.

However when I run the `EXEC` statement I get no data returned, so I assume there is a problem.

Am I doing this right? Is `SUM` the right thing to use? Is there some logical error or something else that I am doing wrong that is causing the procedure to return no values?

This is the create/alter procedure statement:

```
Alter Procedure [dbo].[uspCalc] 
    @Table2ValueSum MONEY OUT
    , @Table3ValueSum MONEY OUT
    , @Table1ValueSum MONEY OUT
As
Select 
    Table1.ClientNo
    , Table1.FileNo
    , Table1.SectionNo
    , Table1.RiskNo
    , Sum(Table1.Table1Value) AS Table1ValueSum
    , Sum(Table2.Table2Value) AS Table2ValueSum
    , Sum(Table3.Table3Value) AS Table3ValueSum 
From 
        Table1  
    LEFT OUTER Join 
        Table2 On Table1.ClientNo = Table2.ClientNo
                 AND Table1.FileNo = Table2.FileNo
                 AND Table1.SectionNo = Table2.SectionNo
                 AND Table1.RiskNo = Table2.RiskNo  
    Left Outer Join 
        Table3 On Table1.ClientNo = Table3.ClientNo
                 AND Table1.FileNo = Table3.FileNo
                 AND Table1.SectionNo = Table3.SectionNo
                 AND Table1.RiskNo = Table3.RiskNo
Where 
       Table1.RiskEndDate IS NULL
       AND Table2.EndDate IS NULL
Group By
       Table1.ClientNo
    , Table1.FileNo
    , Table1.SectionNo
    , Table1.RiskNo
    , Table2.ItemCode
    , Table3.ExtCode
HAVING
    @Table2ValueSum = Sum(Table2.Table2Value)
    AND
    @Table3ValueSum = Sum(Table3.Table3Value)
    AND
    @Table1ValueSum = Sum(Table1.Table1Value)
Go
```

This is the `EXEC` statement:

```
DECLARE @Table2ValueSum MONEY, @Table3ValueSum MONEY, @Table1ValueSum MONEY

EXEC uspCalc @Table2ValueSumOUTPUT, @Table3ValueSum OUTPUT, @Table1ValueSum OUTPUT
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, If I have left out any required information sorry, just say what is needed to help and I will update as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are not assigning any values to the `OUTPUT` variables, so they will all be `NULL`. Then in your proc, you are using these variables in the `HAVING` clause. This will result in your `SELECT` statement returning no results.

You might want to try this:

```
Select 
      @Table1ValueSum = Sum(Table1.Table1Value)
    , @Table2ValueSum = Sum(Table2.Table2Value)
    , @Table3ValueSum = Sum(Table3.Table3Value)

From Table1 

    LEFT OUTER Join Table2 On
        Table1.ClientNo = Table2.ClientNo
        AND
        Table1.FileNo = Table2.FileNo
        AND
        Table1.SectionNo = Table2.SectionNo
        AND
        Table1.RiskNo = Table2.RiskNo   

    Left Outer Join Table3 On
        Table1.ClientNo = Table3.ClientNo
        AND
        Table1.FileNo = Table3.FileNo
        AND
        Table1.SectionNo = Table3.SectionNo
        AND
        Table1.RiskNo = Table3.RiskNo

Where 
    Table1.RiskEndDate IS NULL
    AND
    Table2.EndDate IS NULL

Group By
    Table1.ClientNo
    , Table1.FileNo
    , Table1.SectionNo
    , Table1.RiskNo
    , Table2.ItemCode
    , Table3.ExtCode
```

Comment: I changed it as suggested and also changed the WHERE statement to an OR which returned values for 2 of the columns, however when I run the Query a second time they are all NULL values? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The result will depend on what data is contained in your DB.